# A lemma on a sequence of three morphisms

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, modules

Few months ago, I proved that when there is three morphisms of modules over a commutative ring with zero composition, i.e., a sequence
$$A \xrightarrow{\alpha} B \xrightarrow{\beta} C \xrightarrow{\gamma} D$$
with $\gamma\beta\alpha=0$, then there is an induced exact sequence
$$0 \to \text{ker }\alpha \xrightarrow{i_1} \text{ker }\beta\alpha \xrightarrow{\alpha'} \text{ker }\beta \xrightarrow{i_2} \text{ker }\gamma\beta/\text{im }\alpha \xrightarrow{\beta'} \text{ker }\gamma/\text{im }\beta\alpha \xrightarrow{i_3} \text{coker }\beta \xrightarrow{\gamma'} \text{coker }\gamma\beta \xrightarrow{i_4} \text{coker }\gamma \to 0.$$
in which all maps are canonical.
Using this lemma, it was possible to prove for example the statements about exact couples in this article on my blog: https://fractalofideas.wordpress.com/2019/12/10/closed-complex-of-order-3/

The simple and elementary proof is given here, at the middle of the article: https://fractalofideas.wordpress.com/2019/09/23/how-to-prove-snake-lemma-without-diagrams/

As one may notice, this is nothing but the snake lemma, maybe in its simplest form possible.
Is this worth to submit this result to some academic journal?

Comment: The standard proof of the snake lemma seems pretty simple and elementary to me...

Comment: @lambda I agree with that. That’s my hesitation too. But I could say that this form of the lemma is most easy to apply in many situations.

Comment: A modern point of view on such lemmas in abelian categories makes systematic use of the salamander lemma. See for example https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2007/11/13/anton-geraschenko-the-salamander-lemma/ (by MO founding member Anton Geraschenko).

Comment: @Todd Trimble Thank you for your comment and reference! I think the salamander lemma could also be proved using this lemma as well, which now I’m trying.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to link to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etbcKWEKnvg

Comment: @Sam Hopkins Okay. He was half correct I think :)

Comment: Are there situations where this occurs naturally, i.e. the triple composition is zero but the pair compositions are not?

Comment: @Mark Grant It occurs in any double complex or higher, which goes a same direction twice. Actually, I was asking myself what occur if the composition of many is zero to understand higher dimensional complex.

Comment: This situation was considered by Walther Mayer (who was Albert Einstein's assistant) and Alan D. Campbell in some papers around 1942.  In https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968874 Mayer associates to each simplicial complex a graded abelian group with a boundary operator d that satisfies d^p = 0 for some p (rather than the usual d^2 = 0).  This gives bigraded homology groups, generalizing the groups in your exact sequence.  I believe equation (3.17) in his sequel https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968815 generalizes the exactness (but I have not carefully compared the results).

Comment: @John Rognes I read the definitions and statements in the linked articles and compared the two. I also think you’re correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The short and easy answer is "no, you should not submit it to a research journal".

Comment: I understood. Thanks

Comment: Though just because something is not worth sending to a research journal, that does not always mean it is not worth sending anywhere. If you feel your argument is interesting or novel in some way, there are other options such as a short piece in something like the MAA monthly or Math Horizons, especially if you can sell your argument as educational for students in some way.

Comment: @GregFriedman Thank you a lot for your encouragement.